# Why do the audio and video RTT values differ?

Tags: webrtc

Why do the audio and video RTT values differ? Are they just pings through the RTCP channel?

I would assume they should be the same or roughly the same.

Answer (score 1):

The round trip times are based on the RTCP sender and receiver report and calculated as defined in https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3550#section-6.4.1

Why they would differ is a good question. The timestamps will differ and video sender reports are a lot more frequent but the resulting values should still be roughly the same. What differences are you observing?

Comment: It looks like the diff we're seeing might be related to a bug. Some of the RTT values are over 3000 ms. We'll have to dig into this.

Comment: 3000 is a magic value sometimes used by webrtc to say "I have no idea" ;-)

Comment: Haha. Yeah I assume there’s a ceiling after which the RTT value is simply a “shoulder shrug”.